# Elementary Poncelet Porism proof

Tags: geometry

Is there any elementary proof of the Poncelet Porism for the particular case where the ellipses are circles?

Comment: It is always good to give a reference like this one in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet's_closure_theorem).

Comment: Do you mean "elementary" as in "easy and short", or in the sense of [not requiring complex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_proof)?